# depends_on resource still attempts to run when the parent resource count is zero

Tags: terraform

When the count is 0 for `aws_lb` resource, the `aws_lb_listener` resource still attempts to run even though it is configured to depend on `aws_lb` resource. How can I prevent it from running when `aws_lb` count is 0? `var.create_lb` is set to false so the count should be 0.

This is the error:

```
  on ../modules/vpc/nlb.tf line 31, in resource "aws_lb_listener" "listener":
  31:   load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.myNLB[0].arn
    |----------------
    | aws_lb.myNLB is empty tuple

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

Adding `count` to listener was still producing the error.

Here is the partial code:

```
resource "aws_lb" "myNLB" {
  depends_on = [
    data.aws_vpc.vpc_id,
    data.aws_subnet_ids.public_subnet_ids,
  ]

  count = var.create_lb ? 1 : 0
  name = "myNLB"
  internal = false
  load_balancer_type = "network"
  subnets = data.aws_subnet_ids.public_subnet_ids.ids

  tags = {
    Name = "myNLB"
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "listener" {
  depends_on = [
    aws_lb.myNLB,
    aws_lb_target_group.nlb_tg_port_80,
  ]

  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.myNLB[0].arn
  port = "80"
  protocol = "TCP"

  default_action {
    type = "forward"
    target_group_arn =  aws_lb_target_group.nlb_tg_port_80.arn
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you just `count = var.create_lb ? 1 : 0` for the listener as well?

Comment: Figured it out. I had already tried use count for listener as well, but it was still producing error. After removing the `tfstate` files it is working correctly. I'm trying to apply the change now since `terraform plan` isn't producing any errors

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had to remove the `terraform.tfstate` file and `.terraform` directory to clean up and then run again.

Using count for `listener` was still producing error due to old `terraform.tfstate` file. After removing it, it started working correctly.